# Prevent tab change on Ext.tab.Panel?

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I have one tab where the user must enter information and I want to validate the data when the user tries to change tabs.  I'll prompt the user to verify that he wants to leave if the data input is incomplete.

I added the listener **activeitemchange:** on the tab panel, and I can prompt the user.  However, it seems that Ext.Msg doesn't block the method call and I always "return true" from activeitemchange.

How can I change the code so the tab is only changed if the user clicks 'yes'?

```
Ext.Loader.setConfig({enabled: true});

Ext.application({
    name: "Sencha",

    launch: function () {

        var tabPanel = Ext.create('Ext.tab.Panel', {
            layout: 'card',
            tabBarPosition: 'bottom',
            listeners: {

                activeitemchange: function (me, value, oldValue, eOpts) {
                    console.log("activeitemchange");

                    var oldTabIdx = me.getInnerItems().indexOf(oldValue);
                    var newTabIdx = me.getInnerItems().indexOf(me.getActiveItem());

                    console.log(oldTabIdx + " => " + newTabIdx);
                    if (oldTabIdx == 2) {
//                  me.getTabBar().setActiveItem(2);
                        Ext.Msg.confirm("Leave Screen?", "Are you sure you?", function (response) {
                            console.log(response);
                            if (response === 'no') {
                                console.log("User says stay.");
                                return false;
                            } else {
                                console.log("User says leave.");
                                return true;
                            }
                        });
                    }
                    // Always returns true because Ext.Msg.confirm doesn't block
                    return true; // false prevents tab change
                }
            },
            items: [
                {
                    id: 'tab1',
                    title: 'Home',
                    layout: 'fit',
                    xtype: 'container',
                    iconCls: 'home',
                    items: [
                        {html: 'page #1'}
                    ]
                },
                {
                    id: 'tab2',
                    title: 'Two',
                    layout: 'fit',
                    xtype: 'container',
                    iconCls: 'star',
                    items: [
                        {html: 'page #2'}
                    ]
                },
                {
                    id: 'tab3',
                    title: 'three',
                    layout: 'fit',
                    xtype: 'container',
                    iconCls: 'team',
                    items: [
                        {html: 'page #3'}
                    ]
                }
            ]
        });
        Ext.Viewport.add(tabPanel);
    }
});
```

Attempted fix:

```
Ext.Loader.setConfig({enabled: true});

Ext.application({
    name: "Sencha",

    launch: function () {

        var tabPanel = Ext.create('Ext.tab.Panel', {
            layout: 'card',
            tabBarPosition: 'bottom',
            confirm: true,

            listeners: {

                activeitemchange: {
                    order: 'before',

                    fn: function (list, value, oldValue, eOpts) {
                        var me = this;

                        console.log(me.getConfirm()); // ERROR: getConfirm() is undefined

                        var oldTabIdx = me.getInnerItems().indexOf(oldValue);
                        var newTabIdx = me.getInnerItems().indexOf(value);

                        console.log(oldTabIdx + " => " + newTabIdx);

                        if (oldTabIdx == 2 && me.getConfirm()) {
                            Ext.Msg.confirm("Leave Screen?", "Are you sure you?", function (response) {
                                console.log(response);
                                if (response === 'no') {
                                    console.log("User says stay.");
                                } else {
                                    console.log("User says leave.");
                                    me.setConfirm(false);
                                    me.setActiveItem(newTabIdx);
                                }
                            });
                            return false;
                        } else {
                            me.setConfirm(true);
                        }
                    }

                }
            },

            items: [
                {
                    id: 'tab1',
                    title: 'Home',
                    layout: 'fit',
                    xtype: 'container',
                    iconCls: 'home',
                    items: [
                        {html: 'page #1'}
                    ]
                },
                {
                    id: 'tab2',
                    title: 'Two',
                    layout: 'fit',
                    xtype: 'container',
                    iconCls: 'star',
                    items: [
                        {html: 'page #2'}
                    ]
                },
                {
                    id: 'tab3',
                    title: 'three',
                    layout: 'fit',
                    xtype: 'container',
                    iconCls: 'team',
                    items: [
                        {html: 'page #3'}
                    ]
                }
            ]
        });
        Ext.Viewport.add(tabPanel);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is because Ext.Msg.confirm() is an asynchronous method. It opens a different thread so the listener continues with its normal execution no matter less what is happening on the child thread.

Only way I see is to fire setActiveItem() in the 'yes' callback.

Aditionally, to avoid a confirm loop I added a flag:

```
Ext.application({
    name: "Sencha",

    requires: [
        'Sencha.MyPanel',
        'Ext.MessageBox'
    ],

    launch: function () {
        var tabPanel = Ext.create('Sencha.MyPanel');
        Ext.Viewport.add(tabPanel);
    }
});

Ext.define('Sencha.MyPanel', {
    extend: 'Ext.tab.Panel',

    config: {
        layout: 'card',
        tabBarPosition: 'bottom',
        confirm: true,

        listeners: {
            activeitemchange: {
                order: 'before',

                fn: function (list, value, oldValue, eOpts) {
                    var me = this;

                    console.log(me.getConfirm()); // ERROR: getConfirm() is undefined

                    var oldTabIdx = me.getInnerItems().indexOf(oldValue);
                    var newTabIdx = me.getInnerItems().indexOf(value);

                    console.log(oldTabIdx + " => " + newTabIdx);

                    if (oldTabIdx == 2 && me.getConfirm()) {
                        Ext.Msg.confirm("Leave Screen?", "Are you sure you?", function (response) {
                            console.log(response);
                            if (response === 'no') {
                                console.log("User says stay.");
                            } else {
                                console.log("User says leave.");
                                me.setConfirm(false);
                                me.setActiveItem(newTabIdx);
                            }
                        });
                        return false;
                    } else {
                        me.setConfirm(true);
                    }
                }
            }
        },

        items: [
            {
                id: 'tab1',
                title: 'Home',
                layout: 'fit',
                xtype: 'container',
                iconCls: 'home',
                items: [
                    {html: 'page #1'}
                ]
            }, {
                id: 'tab2',
                title: 'Two',
                layout: 'fit',
                xtype: 'container',
                iconCls: 'star',
                items: [
                {html: 'page #2'}
                ]
            }, {
                id: 'tab3',
                title: 'three',
                layout: 'fit',
                xtype: 'container',
                iconCls: 'team',
                items: [
                    {html: 'page #3'}
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
});
```

Hope it helps-

Comment: Where do you define getter/setter for confirm?  Where in the nesting are these defined?    I tried placing them after the order:'before' line, and after 'confirm: true'.

Comment: for every object property available in config: {} the framework creates the getter and setter ;) magic!. take a look at: http://www.sencha.com/learn/sencha-class-system

Comment: Well, they aren't defined for me.  That's why I'm trying to create them.  I don't have an explicit config: {} in my code.  Did I create it incorrectly?

Comment: I added before the listeners in the code above, (confirm: true,). The listeners are actually in the config

Comment: We seem to have a disconnect.  What I am saying is that when I run your code I get an error saying that me.setConfirm(true) is undefined.  I see the variable.  The functions are not being created for me.

Comment: I added your solution to my question to have a complete solution.  I get an error on this line: console.log(me.getConfirm()); getConfirm() is undefined.  Btw, using Sencha 2.0.0

Comment: Thanks @NicolasGrunfeld, this is a saver :)